# Apache CXF: How to get rid of log warning "Unimplemented getRequestCharacterEncoding() - use org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler"

Tags: java, jetty, cxf

I am using the latest Apache CXF 4.0.1 completely standalone, no EE, no magic, just plain Kotlin code.

To set up my Endpoint, I simply do this:

```kotlin
val jettyHTTPServerEngine = prepareServerForPort(8081)
val endpoint = Endpoint.publish(serviceUrl, MyImplementor, AddressingFeature(true))

private fun prepareJettyServer(port: Int): JettyHTTPServerEngine? =
  with(JettyHTTPServerEngineFactory()) {
    createJettyHTTPServerEngine(port, HTTP_PROTOCOL).apply { sendServerVersion = false }
  }
```

The singleton `Implementor` being an

```kotlin
@WebServiceProvider
@BindingType(SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING)
@ServiceMode(Service.Mode.MESSAGE)
object Implementor : Provider<SOAPMessage> {
  override fun invoke(soapMessage: SOAPMessage): SOAPMessage? {
    // process message here
  }
}
```

Whenever an incoming SOAP message arrives, I get a screaming warning:

> WARN  o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler - Unimplemented getRequestCharacterEncoding() - use org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler

Which refers to the class org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler where you simply find this

```java
@Override
public String getRequestCharacterEncoding()
{
  LOG.warn(UNIMPLEMENTED_USE_SERVLET_CONTEXT_HANDLER, "getRequestCharacterEncoding()");
  return null;
}
```

Great job. No more info. No context. Nothing. This is completely unhelpful.
I searched the web, I searched the code.

I have no idea what they are talking about with this little "hint".

Can anybody help me get rid of this WARN in my log on every incoming request, please?
Someone from this project maybe?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

`ContextHandler` is a `HandlerWrapper` in that its intended use is to provide context-path behaviors to other `Handler` implementations.

In Jetty 10 and Jetty 11 the `ContextHandler` class does not implement the Servlet Spec.

The `ServletContextHandler` does that, which is what the warning message is telling you.

*Note: In Jetty 12, the `ContextHandler` class doesn't contain this method (along with all other superfluous methods), as all of the core Jetty behaviors have no Servlet API remnants left. (To  use servlet spec behaviors, you choose the level of the spec you want via the ee# level and use it via those specific classes)*

To break down the message ...

```
WARN o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler - Unimplemented getRequestCharacterEncoding() - use org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler
```

- **WARN** - this is a warning level logging event
- **o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler** - the logging event was created by the `ContextHandler` class
- **Unimplemented getRequestCharacterEncoding()** this is a Servlet Spec API and as such is unimplemented by this `Handler`.
- **use org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler** - Use the `ServletContextHandler` class instead (of the `ContextHandler`) if you want to use this specific method.

Now for WHY this warning message is output ...

When you call `Request.getRequestCharacterEncoding()`, it has to use the `<context>.getRequestCharacterEncoding()` to know what the context specific character encoding is.  A plain `ContextHandler` doesn't have that knowledge, that's a concept that exists within the scope of a `javax.servlet.ServletContext`, which is provided by the `ServletContextHandler`.

Because you are using Servlet API calls on the `Request` object, you should be using the appropriate Context as well, which is the `ServletContextHandler`.

Comment: Wow. So much text, so little help. Sorry, but could you please look at my lines of code and tell me *where* I need to change anything? I do not need explanation of how logs work or what the message tells me. I need to understand where I get control of which ContextHandler is used. I am not "calling Request.getRequestCharacterEncoding", nor am I "using Servlet API" as you state, I do not even know what this is. I am also not explicitly using Jetty in any version, I am just using Apache CXF 4.0.1. Look at my 10ish lines of code and please explain where I can control that this does not happen.

Comment: Your use of Apache CXF means you are using the Servlet Spec API.  You'll need to use the `ServletContextHandler` instead of the `ContextHandler`

Comment: ...but where do I choose this? I don't see any reference point where I could possibly say "don't use this, use that one!"

Comment: The problem underneath this (and many more libraries) is very bad architecture. Classes should NEVER implement interfaces that they cannot fulfill. It's a violation of the Interface Segregation pattern. Do not design interfaces with too many methods and then classes that don't implement half of the interfaces methods. People who like to understand what's going on will get mad.

Comment: Btw I do use Apache CXF because other people force us to use a SOAP interface... I would have thought no sane IT company would do that in 2023, but hell, was I wrong... Apache CXF was simply the only lib I saw fit to get this with 10 lines of code... But now I have this warning that I simply couldn't care less about flooding my log files. *Sick* It all works, just this stupid warning.

Comment: No more help on how to choose the correct ContextHandler??

Comment: Why do some people simply not answer very concrete questions... It seems Joakim knows something, but does not come to the point to tell us exactly HOW to tell Apache CXF which Handler to really use. This is very unfortunate.

Comment: The answer was provided, twice by me (three times the answer, and once as a comment on this answer).   Apache CXF itself also has the same information, [in its examples, in its demos, in its documentation, and even in the test cases](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Aapache%2Fcxf+ServletContextHandler&type=code).

Comment: Sorry, Joakim, but you do not ever see the context this questions is asked in. I have exactly 5 lines of code - where in those lines of code do I get to specify the ContextHandler to instantiate. I do not see this at all. Please take my lines of code and point where the user decides on which Handler to be used.

Comment: Your link only points to test cases. I am not stupid, I know how to instantiate an object. But this is not helpful. I have no point where I can do this.

Comment: Don't know what you want anymore.  You are using Apache CXF in a non EE way, but also using SOAP which is EE, so you cannot use the non EE Apache CXF techniques (namely `JettyHTTPServerEngineFactory`).  You *MUST* use the EE techniques for Apache CXF if you want to use SOAP.

Comment: You got it. I do not want to use EE at all, I just need SOAP (which has nothing to do with EE...) The problem is: it works JUST FINE - but this warning is annoying as hell. And I wish to disable the warning which is apparently not indicating any problem at all.

Comment: SOAP (the spec) is a Jakarta EE component with requirements for Jakarta Activation (also a Jakarta EE component).  SOAP the (various) implementations add the additional requirement of Jakarta Servlets (also a Jakarta EE spec).  Check your Classpath, I can guarantee with 100% certainty that you have javax.servlet or jakarta.servlet present.  If you remove that jar from your classpath, nothing will work.

Comment: Well, I do not want it to not work... :-) All I want to get rid of is the warning in the log.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue upgrading to jetty 10.x (also logs keeps complaining in 11.x).

After some debugging I realised that something has become picky about incoming Content-Type header. I guess that strictly the server need to know how text/data passed to it is encoded.

So: clients calling needs to state this in headers like:
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

I totally understand that this is not very helpful as a server cannot force its client to pass any headers... Maybe, just maybe you can create an interceptor that intercepts the message before this happens and default Content-Type header to something that works.

Comment: Answering my own "maybe". Turns out this did not help as jetty has opinions before cxf gets the message

Comment: Raised a ticket on cxf asking the same thing here:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-8894

Comment: Raised in June and nobody cares. SOAP is dead, as anyone can see... ;-)